# html javascript code not loaded properly

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
function drawimage()
{
var f=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt1=f.getContext("2d");
    var img1=new Image();
    img1.src="image.jpg";
    cxt1.drawImage(img1,0,0,750,400);
}

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1125" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

drawimage().
```

This is my javascript but when I am running this on browser, only border comes the 1st time and image appears only after refreshing the page. What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the image drawing in a "load" handler:

```
var img1=new Image();
img1.src="image.jpg";
img1.onload = function() {
  cxt1.drawImage(img1,0,0,750,400);
};
```

Comment: is there same code for drawing lines also. On my page lines are sometimes drawn and sometimes after refresh.

Comment: Uhh ... lines?  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: when i try to draw lines, sometimes they are drawn and some not

Comment: That sounds like something you should post as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

the img1.src line MUST be after the onload because if the browser is fast enough (+ maybe image is cached or it's localhost), the image will be loaded just after img1.src is setted. In this case, the onload will not be called.

```
var img1=new Image();
img1.onload = function() {
  cxt1.drawImage(img1,0,0,750,400);
};
img1.src="image.jpg";
```